# Одновременная правка вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, правки

Неоднократно попадал в ситуацию, когда появляется новый вопрос, который необходимо отредактировать, например сделать подсветку синтаксиса, или отформатировать код что бы убрать *скролл*. Заходишь в редактирование, вносишь соответствующие изменения, и тут система сообщает что данный вопрос был изменён.

В этот момент в голове мелькают всякие *нелестные выражения/словосочетания/эпитеты*

Хочется задать вопрос: это так задумано, или это *баг*?

Comment: А как бы вы предложили решить проблему одновременного редактирования?

Comment: @KromStern не позволять зайти в редактирование если уже кем то редактируется например, или позволять зайти но оповещать что данный вопрос уже редактируется. можно же что то придумать. не знаю как Вас а меня крайне де мотивирует подобное поведение

Comment: @Bald56rus возникнет проблема протухания сессий редактирования.

Comment: @Nofate безвыходных ситуаций не бывает:) понял, это так задумано потому что попытка решить может вылиться в большой *геморой*, может тогда напишите ответ, что бы так сказать закрыть эту тему

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так и задумано. Попытка решить это выливается в еще большие проблемы (задача аналогична трехстороннему слиянию в git/SVN, только еще сложнее, т.к. в динамике).